# wrong set base path debug angular 14

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angularbuild

whne I run, I need to pass a `base path` like /pis/

```
ng serve  --serve-path /pis/
```

I do this but it doesn't load anything. Anyone can help me to put a base path in ng serve operation?

Comment: What's the purpose of this exactly ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean `--base-href`?

Example usage:

```
ng serve --base-href /pis/
```

Edit:
From Angular Docs, see mention of `--base-href` [here](https://angular.io/guide/deployment#deploy-to-github-pages)
And another option `--baseHref` [here](https://angular.io/guide/i18n-common-deploy#deploy-multiple-locales).

Comment: This reads more like a comment than an answer to me. One of the primary purposes of the question's comment section is to ask for clarification or more details from the asker.

Comment: Do you have a link to the documentation for this option? I can [see docs for `--serve-path`](https://angular.io/cli/serve), but not for `--base-href`. I'm not an angular dev though. Am I missing something?

Comment: I could not find a direct reference to the `--base-href` option but I see it used everywhere there: [example about deploying to GitHub Pages](https://angular.io/guide/deployment#deploy-to-github-pages). There is also a reference to a `--baseHref` option mentioned [here](https://angular.io/guide/i18n-common-deploy#deploy-multiple-locales)